# Como examinar objetos en Node.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, object

Asigno una variable a un objeto, hago console.log con ella con intención de averiguar y examinar que hay dentro del objeto, pero al arrancar el código en consola (**CLI**)(**PowerShell**), este console.log simplemente me devuelve lo siguiente: `[object] [Object]`

¿Como puedo proceder para ver el objeto, como por ejemplo sucede en javascript en el lado del frontent, cuando hacemos console.log y ejecutamos dentro del navegador?

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías pasar a cadena el objeto Json: JSON.stringify({"name":"binchen"});

Comment: console.table() lo haz probado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un for in:

```js
var objeto = {
 nombre: 'Juan',
 apellido: 'López',
 direccion: {
  calle: 'Sol',
  numero: '1',
  colonia: 'Galaxia'
 }
}

for (var prop in objeto){
  console.log('Propiedad: ' + prop + ' - Valor: ' + objeto[prop])
}

for (var prop in objeto.direccion){
  console.log('Propiedad: ' + prop + ' - Valor: ' + objeto.direccion[prop])
}
```

Como ves, hago dos for in porque dentro del objeto hay otro objeto.

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es """util"""" es el nombre de la bibleoteca!

Quedaria ASI:

```
    const util = require('util')

    console.log(util.inspect(myObject, {showHidden: true, depth: null}))
```

> myObject es tu objeto cambialo y te mostrará todo lo que tiene dentro

Para mas información puede leer aquí

> > https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options

Luego busca "The following example inspects all properties of the util object:"

Espero que te funcione! Saludos